# How to set type of field for async pipe inside an angular-template?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following statement in my template in my table

```html
<span>
{{ row[columns[1].field] | async | beautifyMyString}}
</span>
```

Where as `beautifyMyString` accepts `string | number | undefiend`.

`row[columns[1].field]` on the other hand should be an `Observable<string>`. However, angular state out, that the async pipe will return `Observable<unknown>`. I guess this is because its not clear what the generic `field` is containing. But even if Im doing something like this:

```typescript
    {{ asStringObservable(row[columns[1].field]) | async | beautifyMyString}}
```

where as

```typescript
    asStringObservable(observable: any): Observable<string> {
        return observable as Observable<string>;
    }
```

Angular prints

```
Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number | undefined'.
```

I guess, I have to narrow the field-content before pass its content to the async pipe.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st step: make your pipe accept null, because async pipe can return null sometimes when there is no value yet.

2nd: your colums should contain something more complex than `string` in a `field` field

```js
interface Column<T> {
  field: keyof T;
}
```

and

```
columns: Column<TableRowModel> = ...
```

this way typings will be correctly inferred